# Change jboss server port configuration in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss

When I go to "edit configurations" and add a jboss server then go to the "Startup/Connection" tab, I need to change the port option for debug. But it doesn't let me type in the number. I have to use the up and down buttons. This takes forever and doesn't make sense. Is there some .xml file somewhere that I can edit?
Thanks!

Comment: I thought the right way to do that was to change the Port binding set on run configurations.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: Not on my machine.  Check the start up to make sure you haven't unchecked using the default script.